# How to test spree decorator in original app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I'm making Rails app called "MyApp" with Spree and try test with RSpec.

I read Spree Test App Document, and try test with RSpec.

But I got error

```
~/r/d/MyApp ❯❯❯ bundle exec rspec                                                             

An error occurred while loading ./spec/controllers/spree/home_controller_spec.rb.
Failure/Error:
  describe Spree::HomeController, type: :controller do
    it "render index template" do
      get :index
      response.should render_template(:index)
    end
  end

NameError:
  uninitialized constant Spree
# ./spec/controllers/spree/home_controller_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.

Finished in 0.0004 seconds (files took 0.146 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples
```

> NameError: uninitialized constant Spree
>   I think that this error occured because it only define decorator.
>   Original Controller is defined in Spree gem(core, backend, frontend ...etc).

Detail codes are the following:

MyApp/app/controllers/home_controller_decorator.rb

```
Spree::HomeController.class_eval do
  def index
    do_something
  end
end
```

MyApp/specs/controllers/home_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Spree::HomeController do
  it "render index template" do
    get :index
    response.should render_template(:index)
  end
end
```

MyApp/spec/spec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups
  config.disable_monkey_patching!
  config.order = :random
  Kernel.srand config.seed
end
```

How to test my decorator original logic?
Where should I write code?
Can't test MyApp/spec directory?

Maybe I misunderstand about Spree Test.

Please give me the hint.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

### The Problem

It's not loading Rails so it can't see Spree.

### The Solution

**`MyApp/specs/controllers/home_controller_spec.rb`**

Instead of

```rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe Spree::HomeController do
  # ...
```

you need

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

describe Spree::HomeController do
  # ...
```

### More Information

- `spec_helper` is designed to set up RSpec ready for testing plain Ruby objects
- If your code under test was in the `lib` folder and didn't depend on Rails, this would be fine
- Because Spree depends entirely on Rails, you need to load Rails by `require 'rails_helper'`
- `rails_helper` also requires `spec_helper` but the reverse is not true
- `rails_helper` is much slower to load than `spec_helper` precisely because it boots up Rails

### Anatomy of `rails_helper`

- Rails 5 version
- Your `rails_helper` might look different

```rb
# Load spec_helper
require 'spec_helper'

# Setup Rails to run in test mode
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'

# This is the magic line that runs Rails. Check out config/environment.rb.
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

# Guard against running any tests in production mode
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?

# Load all the rspec rails related goodness
require 'rspec/rails'

# Make sure the migrations are up to date
begin
  ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
rescue ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError => e
  puts e.to_s.strip
  exit 1
end
```

Comment: Oh..I have very simple mistake...
It worked.

I'm sorry in a rudimentary mistake.
Thank you for all your kindness!